# Get All records of previous date from current date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, where-clause

I want all the data from a table which is more than 6 months available in my table. So for that I wrote the below query but it wasn't giving the exact records.

```
Select * from changerequests where lastmodifiedon < sysdate - 180;
```

The issue is I was getting the records for **2nd april, 2020** which is not more than 6 months. Please suggest the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want records that were last modified within the last 6 months, then you want the inequality condition the other way around:

```
where lastmodifiedon > sysdate - 180
```

Note that 180 days is not exactly 6 months. You might want to use `add_months()` for something more accurate:

```
where lastmodifiedon > add_months(sysdate, -12)
```

Comment: I was referring to GMB's answer which utilizes ADD_MONTHS.